# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag - JSX tag already wrapped but keep omitting the error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-redux

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function DataList(props) {

  //creating the ListItem
const dataList = data.map(data => (
  <><span>{data.name}</span>nbsp;<span>{data.age}</span></>
))
const data = [
  { name: 'Daniel', age: 25 },
  { name: 'John', age: 24 },
  { name: 'Jen', age: 31 },
];

  return (
    <h2><span>Name</span>nbsp;<span>Age</span></h2>
    <div>{dataList}</div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <DataList data={ data } />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This keeps omitting

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (7:4)

I wrapped everything but can't figure out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You need to wrap your returning JSX into a single parent component, You can also use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) here as

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-worker-gydhg?file=/src/App.js:0-534)

```
<>
  <h2>
    <span>Name</span>
    nbsp;
    <span>Age</span>
  </h2>
  <div>{dataList}</div>
</>
```

**2)** Since you are using `const` to declare `data` then, you should declare it at the starting of the function.

> variables declared using `let` and `const` cannot be accessed before
> they are declared.

```
  const data = [
    { name: "Daniel", age: 25 },
    { name: "John", age: 24 },
    { name: "Jen", age: 31 }
  ];

  //creating the ListItem
  const dataList = data.map((d) => (
    <>
      <span>{d.name}</span>
      <span>{d.age}</span>
    </>
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend @decpk that answer like to using empty `<>` tag. You should use `<Fragment>` tag. This way increase readability.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment but this is not an answer. It should be a comment. If we talk about the `<>` or `<Fragment>`, that is just a personal preference. We can't impose on someone to do the way we do.

Answer (score -1):

Simply I am using **div** tag, here is the code example for above problem-

```
 return (
    <div>
         <h2><span>Name</span>nbsp;<span>Age</span></h2>
         <div>{dataList}</div>
    </div>
 );
```

Comment: Not necessarily. This would add more elements than necessary to the DOM tree which could (among other things) have performance implications. Using a fragment is often more flexible.